# Hashtable implementation for Delphi 5

Tags: delphi, data-structures, memory-leaks, hashtable

Do you know a good and free Hashtable imlementation for Delphi 5 ?

I need to organize a huge amount of data in a hastable and I am bit worried about memory leak issues that I found in most available implementations on the web.

Tks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can also check out the open-source / formerly commercial [TurboPower SysTools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/tpsystools/).  Not sure how much it is being updated.  At one point Julian Bucknall recommended it over his [EZDSL library](http://www.boyet.com/FixedArticles/EZDSL.html), although that was back when he still worked fur TurboPower and it was being maintained / updated.

Comment: Actually Turbo-Powers LockBox is probably what he wants, the latest version is updated at http://www.songbeamer.com/delphi/

Comment: LockBox does cryptographic hashing - SysTools and EZDSL do hashtables, which are a data structure.

Answer (score 3):

EZDSL is a library of data structures, including a hash table, written by Julian Bucknall of TurboPower and DevExpress... I haven't used them, but I would have high expectations for this guy's code.

http://www.boyet.com/FixedArticles/EZDSL.html

Comment: I have used EZDSL for years with shrink wrapped applications and the code is very good. Good performance, no concerns over memory leaks.

Answer (score 3):

You can try my [GpStringHash](http://omnithreadlibrary.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/src/GpStringHash.pas). Guaranteed no memory leaks, but works only with strings. I *think* it should work in D5.

Answer (score 2):

- http://www.benya.com/code/collections/hashtable.html
- http://delphi.blue-aura.co.uk/forum/showthread.php?t=816

Comment: We have tried the implementation provided by benya.com but we ran into some memory leak issues. Have you tried the second one ?
Tnks for the answer

Comment: No. I use TList,TStringList  or TClientDataSet + BinarySearch in case of huge amount of data.

Answer (score 1):

You can Try to search in [Koders](http://www.koders.com/).
[Here](http://www.koders.com/delphi/fidBF04C36C18D82F69A118F101A20F98EC523DA329.aspx?s=THashTable) you have a simple implementation ([Winjab project](http://www.koders.com/info.aspx?c=ProjectInfo&pid=U5NFKE7M3K28N9L9SLCK8SU31A&s=THashTable)), or [this](http://www.koders.com/delphi/fid02907AFF1132DABC5F684C899D2D01D7D72FEBEC.aspx?s=THashTable) from [JCL](http://www.koders.com/info.aspx?c=ProjectInfo&pid=TXVDAK1CPWYALQ6ALXGN97RGGE&s=THashTable).

NOTE: See the licence of codes before use it.

Answer (score 0):

Peter Below just posted a rework of something he did to the Embarcadero newgroups in the public.attachments. There's something under his profile on the CodeGear site at http://cc.codegear.com/Item/24825 that describes it.

Answer (score 0):

Checkout [DeCAL](http://sourceforge.net/projects/decal/), which includes hash tables and more data structures.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the actual hash-table implementation, the hash-function being used itself is also important.

A good one is a hash function from Bob Jenkins, [read his paper here](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/doobs.html).

This algorithm was improved upon recently for cases where the input is DWord-sized ([See the C-version of it here](http://burtleburtle.net/bob/c/lookup3.c)). This version is faster, and results in two 32-bit hash-values instead of one. (This second hash-value could be used to speed up in-bucket selection for example.)

For those interested, I could paste the Delphi-translation here? (It's about 170 lines of code.)